# Implementing user access restriction Bluetooth LE

Tags: passwords, bluetooth, restrictions

I have been working on a system that needs simple access restriction to a bluetooth module. I was going to use a set pin code, but it turns out that Bt LE no longer uses pairing pins. What would be the best way in BT 4.0 to restrict access to specific devices?
 I am not sure about whitelisting, because the devices that need to access it could change on short notice and I will not have easy access to the module to change who is whitelisted.